# on IOS Safari, disable options on selection but keep selection

Tags: mobile-safari, selection

I want to disable the options that popup on selection (copy, define...) on the IOS version of Safari, but keep the selection. `-webkit-user-select: none;` prevents from selection text, and `-webkit-touch-callout: none;` isn't doing the job either